# Viewing convergent infinite sum as a point on a n-dimensional sphere

Tags: sequences-and-series, spheres

Lets say we have the convergent sum
$$
\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = X \ 
$$
$$
\ X= \sqrt[]{2}-1
$$

And we know that for every value of n:
$$
a_n>0
$$

And you want to find out what Y is in terms of X.
$$
\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2=Y\ 
$$

Square root on both sides gives:
$$
\sqrt[]{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n)^2}=\sqrt[]{Y}\
$$

We also know that Y is convergent.

Now the left side looks like the equation for distance in an n-dimensional space. So my idea was that if I knew how to rotate a point in n dimensions such that the distance from the center is preserved, I could find a point on that sphere for which the sum of its coordinates converges and its easy to calculate. That way I could find out what the value of Y is. My problem is that i have no idea how to rotate a point in N dimensions. Is the idea even worth trying?

Comment: $Y$ can take different values depending on what the $a_n$ are. I think an interesting question is: *what range* of values can $Y$ take? Is this what you mean by your question?

Comment: Or are you giving us the $a_n$ ? You can't have it both ways: either you give us the $a_n$ or you don't.

Answer (score 2):

You can't find $Y$ as a function of $X$. Suppose
$$
a_1 = \sqrt{2} -1
$$
and all the other values of $a_n$ are $0$.
Suppose
$$
b_1 = \sqrt{2}\ \text{  and  }\  b_2 = -1
$$
and all the other values of $b_n$ are $0$.

Then these two sequences have the same $X$ but different $Y$'s.

Comment: I forgot to add that all values of a_n are bigger than 0.

Comment: That doesn't help. Just let the tail of each series be a convergent geometric series. You really can't do this, essentially because $(a+b)^2 \ne a^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Yes, but i know from numerical aproximations that in my example, both X and Y are convergent sums.

Comment: If you have more information about this question because of the context in which it arose then you should provide all that information _in the question_, not in a sequence of comments. Perhaps you have asked an xy question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem .  But unless there is a lot more information you will not be able to find $Y$ from $X$.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. I want to find an N dimensional rotation such that it transforms the point (a1,a2...a_n) into a point with coordinates that when I add them up they equal a sum that can be expressed in terms of X.

Comment: If that's your point I am missing it still. I don't understand.  If you can [edit] the question to provide an explicit example when $n=2$ (where rotations are easy) perhaps someone can help.